# multi-line literal works in python2 but not in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, multiline

I have the following code:

```
print '''
Hello World
''''
```

It works well with Python 2 but does not work with Python 3:

```
Python 3.2.3 (default, Dec 10 2012, 06:30:54) 
[GCC 4.5.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print '''
... hello world
... '''
  File "<stdin>", line 3
    '''
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use `print()` as a function in python3. http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function

Comment: You should read through the docs on what has changed between 2 and 3, because there are other significant changes that are less easy to stumble upon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a problem of multi-line, but a problem of `print`.

`print` was replaced with a function `print()` in python 3, so that you have to call it as a function.

- won't work in Python 3: `print 'hello'`
- the one works instead:
  `print('hello')`

For your case, try

```
print('''
Hello, 
World
''')
```